# new Image src attribute and base64 image issues - trucation

Tags: javascript, image, base64, src

novice question perhaps - ultimately trying to pass an image from a main page to pop-up for printing

**main page** > uses a canvas which is then converted...

```
  var image = dwnCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  sessionStorage.setItem("imgTAG", image);
```

console.log(image) returns lengthy base64 image info on main page

**pop-up page** > not sure why session variable truncated

```
 <img id="QR-code" src="" />
 <script>
       myImage = new Image();
       myImage = sessionStorage.getItem("imgTAG");
       document.getElementById("QR-code").src = myImage;
 </script>
```

console.log(myImage) returns original lengthy base64 image info.  console.log(document.getElementById("QR-code")) returns a truncated src of ~ 60 characters
`i.e. <img id="QR-code" src="data:image/png;base64,iV…AAFMgHIEAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">`

The PNG image is present in pop-up but transparent - I assume due to incomplete src/base64 info?

Thanks in advance
j

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the max size of localStorage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values)

Comment: It is quite possible that your image's size is more than 5MBs which is the limit of localStorage.

Comment: Good thought - Thanks but image is a QR code... it is small - 1.6 KB.  I have a function to download the QR code image on the main page and it is rendered properly in the resulting file.